# How to data binding two UI Elements so that they can update each other immediately in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, data-binding

Suppose I want to databinding two TextBox. I can do it in XAML:

```
<TextBox x:Name="FirstBox" Text="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay, ElementName= SecondBox}"></TextBox>
<TextBox x:Name="SecondBox"></TextBox>
```

Or, I can do it programmatically.

```
    Binding binding = new Binding("Text");
    binding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
    binding.Source = SecondBox;
    FirstBox.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, binding);
```

The problem is, when I type something in SecondBox, it immediately reflects in FirstBox. However, typing in FirstBox doesn't show in SecondBox immediately. SecondBox is updated only when focus out FirstBox.

Surely, I can build another Binding for SecondBox. But, is there any other way to make change in FirstBox immediately update SecondBox?

Comment: Oddly enough, you can do this easily in Flash...

Comment: @Fiarr: Oddly enough, this question isn't about Flash.

Answer (score 3):

There are probably other ways that include chunks of code but I can't think of an **easier** way if that is what you are really asking.  Why would you not use another binding on the SecondBox to watch the first (I'm assuming this is some simplification of a scenario where doing any of this actually makes sense)?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with a little bit of code. The Xaml looks like this:

```
<TextBox x:Name="tb1" Text="{Binding Path=Text, ElementName=tb2, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" TextChanged="tb1_TextChanged" />
<TextBox x:Name="tb2" />
```

This is the same as what you have, except that we are setting "UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit" and we are registering for the TextChanged event. By default, bindings on TextBox.Text get updated when the TextBox loses focus. By setting "UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit" we are overriding the default update behavior and we need to explicitly say when to update the bindings. So we have the TextChanged event handler that looks like this:

```
private void tb1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    tb1.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateSource();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is expected behavior for a TextBox.  From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278072(VS.95).aspx

Updating the Data Source 
In TwoWay bindings, changes to the target automatically update the source, *except when binding to the Text property of a TextBox. In this case, the update occurs when the TextBox loses focus*.

I think you need to also bind the Text property on the second TextBox to get the behavior you want as Anthony suggested.